# Filtering output with Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a script that uses `boto3` to loop through all of my AWS accounts to get a list of `CloudTrail` trails from each `AWS` account that I own. The issue I am having is that the trails were made using StackSets, so the names are all dynamic. So, when I try to filter by trail name, it is not scalable to go into every account and manually find the name as I own a lot of accounts. When I run my script, I see the trail name I want, but how would I go about filtering just for that specific trail name? Below is my code and the output.

`CODE:`

```
import boto3

def get_sts_token(**kwargs):
    role_arn = kwargs['RoleArn']
    region_name = kwargs['RegionName']
    sts = boto3.client(
        'sts',
    region_name=region_name,
    )
    token = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName='GetInstances',
        DurationSeconds=900,
    )
    return token["Credentials"]

def get_acct_nums():
    region_name = 'us-east-1'

    dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    dynamo_response = dynamo.scan(TableName='AllAccountNums')

    for item in dynamo_response['Items']:
        account = item['Accounts']['S']

        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam: 
    {}:role/ExecutionRole".format(account)
        tokens = get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName=region_name)

        access_key = tokens['AccessKeyId']
        secret_key = tokens['SecretAccessKey']      
        session_token = tokens['SessionToken']

        ctrail = boto3.client('cloudtrail',
            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
            aws_session_token=session_token)

        ctrail_response = ctrail.describe_trails()

        for trail in ctrail_response['trailList']:
            trail_name = trail['Name']

            print(trail_name)

get_acct_nums()
```

`Output:`

```
StackSet-trail-56ab8f59-F7VFM147fe3

cloud-trail-7327093746523

StackSet-trail-03353e-1HLJF22QI1Dw2

cloud-trail-5702290092543
```

etc. etc.

I would only like this line of output: `StackSet-trail-xxxx-yyyy` (which isn't always the first line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterate through all elements, this will give you only the name of the first element

```
ctrail_response['trailList'][0]['Name']
```

However, if you want only the first line of StackSet-trail:

```
for trail in ctrail_response['trailList']:
    trail_name = trail['Name']
    if 'StackSet-trail' in trail_name:
        print(trail_name)
        break   # remove this if you want all StackSet-trail to appear
```

Comment: What if it is not always the first element?

Comment: i edit my answer as well, still not sure if you want 1 or more results, but both options handled